# How to split a string and then embed the second string (link) into the first string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I have this RSS Feed I'm working with currently.

When I retrieve an item from the RSS feed, the following is displayed

> Google Home Page http://www.google.com

How can I split this string, so that I can embed the second part of it (http://www.google.com) into the first part(Google Home Page)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "embed"? Do you mean that you want to create an anchor tag that links to the URL and used the text as the "clickable" text?

Comment: My understanding is to create <a href="http://...">Google....</a>?

Comment: `var a = string.split('http'); var output = '<a href="http' + a[1] + '">' + a[0] + '</a>'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this will be the string:

```
var string = "Google Home Page http://www.google.com";
```

Then we split it:

```
var split = string.split('http'); // ['Google Home Page ', '://www.google.com']
```

Then we create an `a` element:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
```

Then we add the link as the `href` attribute of your anchor element:

```
a.href = 'http' + split[1];
```

And then we add the text as `textContent` of your anchor element:

```
a.textContent = split[0];
```

And finally we add the element to the body:

```
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Here an example:

```js
var string = "Google Home Page http://www.google.com";
var split  = string.split('http');
var a      = document.createElement('a');
a.href     = 'http' + split[1];
a.textContent = split[0];

document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: @Cereal This will only work in this pattern, in this order. As long as it contains HTTP and the title before it, it will work - you will always need _some_ idea of what pattern you will be getting back. You could try to do this with regex to get the URL out, but I'm not a great fan or user of Regex.

Comment: I had to change the `a.textcontent` to `a.text` and everything else worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First - exclude the link by using following RegEx pattern (searches for string which starts with `http://`).

`/http:\/\/.*[^\W+]/g`

The matched value (Array) is being stored into `url`, now we are able to create the anchor element. (the value of `href` is the element 0 inside our matches array).

The link content is being generated by replacing the URL with empty space inside the `retrievedResult`. `trim()` is optional, I've used it just to remove remaining space.

```
retrievedResult.replace(url[0], "").trim()
```

Finally you can append the built anchor element.

```js
var retrievedResult = "Google Home Page http://www.google.com";
var re = /http:\/\/.*[^\W+]/g;
var url = retrievedResult.match(re);
var anchor = '<a href="' + url[0] + '" target="_blank">' + retrievedResult.replace(url[0], "").trim() + '</a>';
$('body').append(anchor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a case where `regex` can be a good solution. Are there any string exceptions to this?

Comment: @somethinghere honestly I'm not really familiar with exceptions in JS

Comment: Actually just wondering if there are any strings the regex does not cover :)

Comment: @somethinghere Oh, well, not sure which strings may be not covered. But I've discovered only one "mistake" in it - everything after the link address will be also captured. Like if there is `"Google Home Page 'http://www.google.com'"` , the match will return `http://www.google.com'`. The single quote at the end is still included

Comment: @somethinghere figured out how to fix the "single-quote issue". `/http:\/\/.*[^\W+]/g` . Matches everything (starting with `http://`) until first non-word character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get to your result

Working Example:

```
//This is HTML part
<div id="linkcontainer"></div>
<input id="str" value='Google Home Page http://www.google.com'>
<a id="createlink">CreateLink</a>
```

---

```
//This is js part
$('#createlink').click(function(){
  createLink();
});

//function that makes link
function createLink(){
  var str = $('#str').val();
  var http = str.indexOf('http');
  var url = str.substring(http);
  var text = str.substring(0,http);
  $('#linkcontainer').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+text+'</a>');
}
```

[Try this code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8up3a068/)